# Best way to update database while program is running

Tags: python, csv, updating

I have a problem regarding (I think) concurrency in Python.

So I have a main program constantly running and updating like every 10 minutes. It's crucial that this main program is abled to run as fast as possible. The main program accesses a database I have implemented in the form of a csv file which is then used as a dictionary in the main program.

Now it's my plan to update said database with the resulting real life data which will most probably differ from the original database. This doesn't have to happen constantly, it's more than enough to update it every 24 hours.

so something like this would happen constantly:

```
p = ReadFromCSV.Parameters()
p.load('data.csv')
params = p.get_parameters(0.6, 0.7, 25)

doSomething(params)
```

and the params would then be changed like once a day with what actually turned out to be the real life params.

How can I manage to run this using and updating independently?

Comment: Check the date/time stamp of your CSV file and do not re-populate your dictionary if it has not changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Could I change only one value in the dictionary or would I always have to update the whole thing?

Comment: It depends on how you load your data. If you have a field in your csv that tells you if a value has been changed, then you can use it when loading your file - but it might be easier (and maybe faster) to load everything with pandas or some library.

Comment: Time difference (if any) between updating "*one value*" and "*the whole thing*" will be immeasurably small.